# Dynamically show a panelGroup when an event happens (JSF/ICEFACES)

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I want to show a panelGroup dynamically.

In this code, I have boxes which can be filled up. When the last available box is filled up with data, a panelGroup with a new set of boxes should show up.

```
<ice:panelGroup binding="#{myPage.boxes0to9}" />
<ice:panelGroup binding="#{myPage.boxes10to19}" />
```

How do I let the second panelGroup display only when the last box in #{myPage.boxes0to9} has been filled in?

Thanks!

Comment: what's the JSF and IceFaces version you're working with?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza IceFaces 1.8 and JSF 2.0 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by wrapping the `<ice:panelGroup>` with a div and show/hide it by a javascript check:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arrInputs = new Array(9);
    function checkInputsFulfilled(value, index) {
        arrInputs[index] = (value == "");
        var filled = true;
        for(var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
            if (arrInputs[i]) {
                filled = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = filled ? "block" : "none";
    }
</script>

<ice:panelGroup binding="#{myPage.boxes0to9}">
    <!-- your 9 inputs (or more) here, I'll write 1 as a sample -->
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.attribute1}" onchange="checkInputsFulfilled(this.value, 0);" />
</ice:panelGroup>
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none">
    <ice:panelGroup binding="#{myPage.boxes10to19}">
    </ice:panelGroup>
</div>
```

You can also do it using an ajax support and rendered a JSF component that wraps the second `<ice:panelGroup>` but this will have a big impact when you just empty one of yout starting inputs and the group should hidden. Of course, this last behavior is controlled in the javascript, if you dont want it just modify it :).